# A stronger condition than planar graph?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, graph-theory

Is there a name for this condition on a graph: a graph that can be embedded in the plane (planar), in such a way that of its univalent vertices do not lie inside any face?

So, one can think of this graph as being built from polygons glued along edges, and then removing some of the boundary edges.

Comment: It's perhaps more consistent to say "...lie inside the external face" (or "...lie inside a single face" since we can make any face the external face by redrawing) instead of "...do no lie inside any face".

Comment: Thanks Rebecca, that's a good point. I was going to say that the when the univalent vertices are glued together, one gets a graph that can be embedded on the sphere. But, surely there must be a name for this condition?